# making webpage looks same on different screens

Tags: css, screen, html

I have a [webpage](http://ferhan.ferohost.com) made by me. At this moment, on different screens, it is looking pretty different.

On my computer the "Sales" text is looking like this (which is I want):

FIRST IMAGE:
[image]

Whereas on another computer(with different screen size), its looking in this way(which is not I want):

SECOND IMAGE:
[image]

In this SECOND IMAGE, the sales text is going far left for some reasons (on different screen) which is not I want. I want it to be on the top of hands image as depicted in the FIRST IMAGE.

The CSS codes which I am using for the sales text are:

```
.sales .text1 {
    padding-left: 450px;
    color: #0275d8;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I am wondering what changes I need to make in CSS so that its look same on different screen size computers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative measurements  like percentage,etc to avoid this, additional you can use media queries to have a different behavior depending of many factors like the screen width

Comment: Media queries is for mobile view. At this moment, my webpage is looking different on different screen size computers at full screen.

Comment: The "Sales" text on my computer is over the hands(which is I want) whereas on another computer with different screen size it is going far left which is not I want.

Comment: I have posted the CSS code. Let me know what changes do I need to make there to get it fixed.

Comment: Media queries only for mobile? Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: My bad. We use for different screen sizes as well.

Comment: Just checking what changes do i need to make in CSS code to get it fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Awesome question, you want to make your webpage responsive. 
check out that link, I believe it has exactly what you are looking for.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, I have changed `padding-left: 450px` to `0` value and added `text-align: right` so that `See More` link will not be cut-off.

```
.sales .text1 {
    padding-left: 0;
    color: #0275d8;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
```